# How to get an attribute of an object with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

People, I have a `array of object`:

```js
this.state = [{
  "456": {
    "name": "PonPon",
    "gerente": "sun2",
    "years": 25,
    "city": "W.T"
    "country": "BRAZIL"
  },
  "789": {
    "name": "PiPon",
    "gerente": "sun1",
    "years": 20,
    "city": "LAS VEGAS",
    "country": "EUA"
  }
}]
```

And a `input`

```html
<input/> 
<button> search </button>
```

- **What I want**.

I would want like, for example:
I typped the number `456` in `input`, I wanted him to return the attributes:

1. name
2. gerente
3. years
4. city
5. country

And that attributes were for other array empty. Example:

```js
const arrayEmpty = [{
  "name": "PonPon",
  "gerente": "sun2",
  "years": 25,
  "city": "W.T",
  "country": "BRAZIL"
}]
```

Or something like with that.

For after to use that array. Someone would can help me?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question as well. Are you just trying to get an item by it's id in the array and then putting it in `arrayEmpty`?
Also, is this to be done as the user types in an id?

Comment: For example, you entered the number 456, it would return: `name, gerente, years, city and country`

And just after the return I wanted to store them in an empty array

Comment: The idea is, from an ID, to return all those values.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for the encapsulating array. You plan use just the object within. Here is an example search function you can adapt for your react code.

```
function search(idToFind) {
    const ids = {
        "456": {
            "name": "PonPon",
            "gerente": "sun2",
            "years": 25,
            "city": "W.T",
            "country": "BRAZIL"
        },
        "789": {
            "name": "PiPon",
            "gerente": "sun1",
            "years": 20,
            "city": "LAS VEGAS",
            "country": "EUA"
        }
    };
    let keys = Object.keys(ids), index = keys.indexOf(idToFind);
    if (index > -1) {
        return ids[idToFind];
    }
    return [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So... there was a bit to do but I have a sample app working.

First of all, I don't see the need of your object to be an array. Is this from an API call? If not, I would suggest just having an array, like this:

```
list: {
        "456": {
          "name": "PonPon",
          "gerente": "sun2",
          "years": 25,
          "city": "W.T",
          "country": "BRAZIL"
        },
        "789": {
          "name": "PiPon",
          "gerente": "sun1",
          "years": 20,
          "city": "LAS VEGAS",
          "country": "EUA"
        }
      }
```

Now... You need to handle your input which is expecting the possible id. I have created the function called `handleChange` which is fired off on the `onChange` event, in other words, whenever the input is changed.

```
<input type='number' value={this.state.currentId} onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(evt.target.value)} />
```

You now need a couple extra states to store both the id you are looking for and the object you found if any. So as you can see, I created the `currentId` state which will hold whatever you put in the input and the `foundObject` state which will hold whatever object you found.

Next, lets see what to o in the actual `handleChange` function:

First off, you will grab your list array, and look through it until you find an object of matching id, comparing it to whatever value your input was put in. If an object matches that, you will set your `foundObject` state as that.

I do this by iterating over the object's (in the array) keys. Which is done like this:

```
// search for the object:
Object.keys(list[0]).forEach(x => {
  if (x === currentId) {
    console.log('hello')
    this.setState({foundObject: list[0][x]})
  }
})
```

Of course, by the end of this function, don't forget to also set the `currentId.

Now you have all you need. In your render function, just render your `foundObject`.

Here is a working version of the app:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentId: null,
      list: [{
        "456": {
          "name": "PonPon",
          "gerente": "sun2",
          "years": 25,
          "city": "W.T",
          "country": "BRAZIL"
        },
        "789": {
          "name": "PiPon",
          "gerente": "sun1",
          "years": 20,
          "city": "LAS VEGAS",
          "country": "EUA"
        }
      }],
      foundObject: null
    }
  }
  handleChange(currentId) {
    const { list } = this.state
    
    // search for the object:
    Object.keys(list[0]).forEach(x => {
      if (x === currentId) {
        console.log('hello')
        this.setState({foundObject: list[0][x]})
      }
    })
    
    this.setState({currentId: currentId})
  }
  
  render(){
    const { foundObject } = this.state
    const renderObject = foundObject ? (
      <div>
        <p>Name: {foundObject.name}</p>
        <p>Gerente: {foundObject.gerente}</p>
        <p>Years: {foundObject.years}</p>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    ) : <p>No objects of this id were found.</p>
    return (
     <div>
        <input 
          type='number'
          value={this.state.currentId}
          onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(evt.target.value)}
         />
        <h3>Found object:</h3>
        {renderObject}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```